# Initialize only when needed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method that gets called occasionally. It relies on a property that I don't want to instantiate unless that method is called, but at the same time I don't want to reinstantiate the property if it is already instantiated. Is this what lazy loading is for?

I'm currently using:

```
property = property ?? Property()
```

and that seems to be working fine, but I want to do a sanity check on this approach.

Comment: Yes, that's what lazy properties are for.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you need lazy loading property like [described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in "Lazy Stored Properties" section

Comment: For completeness, it is worth noting that global constants and variables (when defined outside of main.swift) and static constants and variables are always lazily initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is declare the property as lazy, and it will only be initialized when needed.

```
class MyClass {
  lazy var myLazyArray = [String]()
}

var myObject = MyClass() // myObject.myLazyArray still not initialized
myObject.myLazyArray.append("hello") // Now we're in business!
print(myObject.myLazyArray)
```

Comment: Okay cool, I didn't know lazy properties were only initialized once. So if I did `lazy var property = Property()` and threw a bunch of `property = Property()` in some method, it would only get initialized once and not reset to a new Property every time?

Comment: Once for each instance of the MyClass. Here's a little more complex version of what @diatrevolo shared: *lazy var myMethod: Int -> Int = { [weak self] _ in    return 0 }*

Comment: Referring to the @RyJ comment above, more than that, you would use property AS IF it were initialized.  It will initialize it on first use.